# Best effective dart style: Words order for UpperCamelCase according to the importance of each word?

Tags: dart

I'm starting with Dart and I want to do write effective code from the beginning.

My doubts are: **¿Which order I have to follow when I name class' with composed words?¿It's the most important going first or last?¿How I know which one is the most important one?**

For example, **which one will be the best one?**: (For an avatar builder app)

```
class SkinCollection {}
class ClothingCollection {}
class NoseCollection {}
class MouthCollection {}
enum SkinType {}
enum ClothingType {}
enum NoseType {}
enum SkinColors {}
enum ClothingColors {}
enum NoseColors {} 
...
```

or this one:

```
class CollectionSkin {}
class CollectionClothing {}
class CollectionNose {}
class CollectionMouth {}
enum TypeSkin {}
enum TypeClothing {}
enum TypeNose {}
enum ColorsSkin {}
enum ColorsClothing {}
enum ColorsNose {} 
...
```

And **Why it's that one better?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former is [recommended](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#prefer-putting-the-most-descriptive-noun-last) by the Dart style guide. It says:

> #### PREFER putting the most descriptive noun last.
>
> The last word should be the most descriptive of what the thing is. You can prefix it with other words, such as adjectives, to further describe the thing.

So, for example, take `SkinCollection` vs `CollectionSkin`. The thing is not "a skin", it *is* a collection, so `Collection` is the most important noun here, what the thing *is*, with the `Skin` being a modifier to that, not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was using `SkinCollection` but I saw many examples in github with something like `CollectionSkin` and English is nor my native language so I started to think that maybe I got it in the wrong way.